# Adding lights at execution time in Gazebo-Fuerte

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS and running some simulations in Gazebo: the environment is an apartment with several rooms. During the simulation I need to switch on and off the light depending on the events that happen in the apartment.

In ROS-Electric I did it with the code below, but in Fuerte this code results in a link that oscillates like a pendulum... I tried to take a look in the forum but I didn't get any result... Do you see mistakes in the following code or should I go in another direction? In the second case, I didn't find useful links to add the light a run time.

Thanks

from shell:

rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file "path_to_the_urdf_file" -urdf -model light_k
the file related to the light is:

```
 1. <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    
    <robot name="light_kitchen"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
        xmlns:gazebo="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#gz"
        xmlns:model="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#model"
        xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
        xmlns:body="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#body"
        xmlns:geom="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#geom"
        xmlns:joint="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#joint"
        xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
        xmlns:rendering="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#rendering"
        xmlns:renderable="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#renderable"
        xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
        xmlns:physics="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#physics">
    
      <link name="bulb_k">    <inertial>
        <mass value="1" />
                <com xyz="1.81 3.59 2.15" />
                <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0"
    iyz="0.0" izz="0" />
            </inertial>
    
            <visual>
                <origin xyz="1.81 3.59 2.15" rpy="0 0 0" />  <!--   definition of the visual postion of
    the object!! -->
                <geometry>
                    <sphere radius="0.0001" />
                </geometry>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="1.81 3.59 2.15" rpy="0 0 0" />
                <geometry>
                    <sphere radius="0.0001" />
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
    
        <gazebo reference="bulb_k">
            <model:renderable name="light_k">
                <xyz>0.0 0.0 0.0</xyz>
                <static>true</static>
                <light>
                    <type>point</type>
                    <diffuseColor>0.1 0.1 0.1</diffuseColor>
                    <specularColor>.01 .01 .01</specularColor>
                    <attenuation>0.1 0.1 0.0001</attenuation>
                    <range>4</range>
                </light>
            </model:renderable>
        </gazebo> </robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1413/adding-lights-at-execution-time-in-gazebo-fuerte/) by [Maurizio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/217/maurizio/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe this tutorial has the solution to your problem: [Factory world plugin](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/plugins/factory)

In many words, this tutorial demonstrates how to insert predefined and custom models into a running simulation in the Gazebo.

Take a look in option 3: Insert model from file via message passing.

I hope that it helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1